# Inject models in laravel's controllers's constructors or laravel's controller's concrete function

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, model, controller

Imagine situation that in laravels constructor(PostController) I need to Inject 3 models: User, Post and Comment.

I have two scenarios:

1) Inject these 3 Models all in controllers constructor and then I use this controllers variables in concrete functions like this: `$this->post`

2) Inject these models in concrete controller's functions whenever, wherever needed (For example `index(Post $post)`);

which of these two is better practice?  In first scenario, in index function I only use `$this->post` variable, but I also create `$this->comment` and `$this->user` because I need them in other functions? but I don't need them in index, so I inject and create them for nothing whenever I call index by addressing index specific route. Isn't that bad? so which of these is better?

Comment: you can't inject Models. why would you want that? there may be a better solution for your problem

Comment: Because I don't want to write $user = new User(); then I will not be able to mock this $user variable when testing

Comment: Also I can inject models

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, When you inject a **model** in a controller **method** it means that you're trying to bind a route value to the model. In a simple term, you want laravel to auto-*magically* fetch that model for you.

On the other hand, when you inject it via the `__construct()`, you want those models to be instantiated for your use within the class. In simple term, you want Laravel to create a new instance of that model within the class.

Let's go practical:

**First situation**

```
//routes

Route::get('/ninjas/{ninja}') //ninja is a number or anything that identifies a model

//Controller

public function index(Ninja $ninja)
{        
    //$ninja will be a resolved model
}
```

**Other situation,**

```
public function __construct(Ninja $ninja)
{        
    $this->ninja = $ninja;
}

public function index($ninja_id)
{        
    $this->ninja->find($ninja_id)
}
```

As you can see from the above examples, it depends on the use case. That is, if you intend to bind a model to the route then, you inject to controller methods otherwise if you want use your models in a *cleaner* way then, up to the constructor.

Cheers!

> PS: A side note, asking for *best practice* normally attracts opinionated answer which would make finding a *correct* answer hard.

Comment: what do you mean in "you're trying to bind a route value to the model"

Comment: @O.Shekriladze I explained in the first sentence: `In a simple term, you want laravel to auto-magically fetch that model for you.` What it mean is what I showed in the first situation, where you pass an id into the route e.g `ninjas/1` and in your controller method Laravel fetches that model for you.